# How far away is too far to catch a Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was playing last night and I tapped on a Pokémon to try and catch them and an error message popped up saying "The Pokémon is too far away." The Pokémon was within my radius, I wasn't driving, and my GPS signal was stable, so I don't know why it would say that. How far away is too far away to catch a Pokémon, or why else would this message appear?

Answer (score 1):

The farthest away that you can catch pokémon is **40 meters** away from you, but since it is not very accurate, but sometimes you may be able to catch pokemon from 60-100 meters since it is not very accurate. You can **find more information** about that **at this link:** https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4qxb84/question_about_the_max_range_to_interact/

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself...